# How do you change the default topic subscription options while using Rosbridge for Foxglove?

Tags: ros, foxglove-studio

We are using [Foxglove](https://foxglove.dev/) as a visualization tool for our ROS2 Foxy system on Ubuntu 20, but we are running into bandwidth issues with the rosbridge websocket.  We have plans to switch to using the foxglove_bridge websockets since they advertise performance improvement, but are waiting until we migrate to ROS Humble.

When a client initiates a subscription to a topic, it can also pass along options to the server to throttle the message rate for each topic.

Where do I change those options?  They must be set within the client, but I couldn't find anything within the GUI to set it.

I'm running foxglove-studio from binaries installed through apt. The only source code I have for the foxglove-studio is a few custom extension panels.

My temporary fix is to filter out the topics I want to throttle and hard-code the `throttle_rate` option within the rosbridge server before the options are passed to the subscriber handler.

This will work for the demo we have coming up, but I'm searching for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foxglove Studio currently uses a [hard-coded set of parameters](https://github.com/foxglove/studio/blob/bdf794f5393430c1651a50c85bf2878636b66bc6/packages/studio-base/src/players/RosbridgePlayer.ts#L456-L460) for creating the [roslib Topic](http://robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/Topic.html) object and so does not support throttling. To achieve this you'd currently need to either:

- patch the Studio source and build it yourself
- patch the server as you've currently done, or
- create a separate downsampled topic (e.g. using [topic_tools/throttle](https://github.com/ros-tooling/topic_tools)).